# Are hag-children innately evil?

Tags: dnd-5e

Given the following from the 5E MM (pg 176).

> **Monstrous Motherhood**. Hags propagate by snatching and devouring human infants. After stealing a baby from its cradle or its mother's
>   womb, the hag consumes the poor child. A week later, the hag gives
>   birth to a daughter who looks human until her thirteenth birthday,
>   whereupon the child transforms into the spitting image of her hag
>   mother.
>
> Hags sometimes raise the daughters they spawn, creating
>   covens. A hag might also return the child to its grieving parents,
>   only to watch from the shadows as the child grows up to become a
>   horror.

Would a hag-child raised by it's parents end up necessarily evil?  Or merely horrific?

Comment: Is your question “can a hag be raised to be not evil?”

Comment: This is likely a setting-specific question, and even then, some settings may not have an answer for this question. Voting to close as Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: While I support closing as Primarily Opinion-Based, I did receive a response from Mike Mearls.  https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/713153356517117953

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The intent I read in the quoted passage is that it should be evil, however it is up to the DM. The MM p. 7:

> Feel free to depart from it and change a monster's alignment to suit
>   the needs of your campaign. If you want a good-aligned green dragon,
>   or an evil storm giant, there's nothing stopping you.

I believe it might be an interesting story to redeem a hag child.

Similar questions appeared about Demons and Celestrials a while ago here:
[Can a demon or devil be redeemed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76819/can-a-demon-or-devil-be-redeemed)