# Has a demon ever switched sides in the blood war?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore

Within the background of the blood war the Demon Graz’zt is presented as a former devil who switched alignments and joined the demon ranks.

Is there any example within the lore of DnD (from any edition) of a demon doing the equivalent? Switching sides to become a devil, is this possible in terms of what a demon is how it is formed and maintains its existence?

Just to clarify I am looking for an example of a powerful being, named character etc as opposed to a generic type of creature (for instance succubi)

Comment: Are you looking for a specific single entity? I believe succubi _in general_ switched from demons to devils in 4e, but I'm not sure if that fits what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi sorry no looking for an in game example of a major demonic being rather then a subclass or a type of demon.

Comment: Would you count a tanar'ri and a baatezu who both abandoned their respective sides of the bloodwar out of friendship, and then together worked against against both sides? Because that did happen once.

Comment: I am looking for either, and am happy with any edition of DnD. I have started sketching out an NPC Major Demon and the circumstances that cause it to make the switch but if there are examples buried in the history of DnD I can draw on that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding lore about unusual behaviour by fiends, you might have a look at the following answer: [Can a demon or devil be redeemed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76819/can-a-demon-or-devil-be-redeemed/104956#104956)

Here are the most relevant parts of that answer:

- In the 2e Planescape (PS) adventure book "The Well of Worlds", there is a cornugon-succubus (baatezu-tanar'ri) love affair.
- "The Chant of the War" book from the 2e PS accessory "Hellbound: The Blood War" describes a babau (tanar'ri), osyluth (baatezu) pair named Bb'bray and Antralius (page 31). They still hold on to their normal alignments, but have overcome their racial hatred and are trying to stop the Blood War together to save fiend lives. It is claimed that they have managed to convince some.
- Zem'Jil is a 3.5e-era succubus described in Dragon #350 (page 33, December 2006). She agreed to be transformed by the diety Wee Jas and became LE.