# Must a half-fiend be evil?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, alignment

The half fiend alignment says that it has any evil alignment. Can that be different by 1 step during character creation or change to a non evill one later on?

(thus chaotic neutral, lawful neutral or neutral neutral)

Comment: Strongly related: [Can a half-dragon's alignment change from their dragon's alignment type?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30172/4563)

Comment: Yepp with the only difference being that I'm asking about pathfinder and he about 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Monster Entry Format](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-entry-format)

> #### Alignment, Size, and Type
>
> While a monster's size and type remain constant (unless changed by the application of templates or other unusual modifiers), alignment is far more fluid. The alignments listed for each monster represent the norm for those monsters—they can vary as you require them to in order to serve the needs of your campaign. **Only in special cases is this more fixed,** such as creatures with an Intelligence of 2 or lower (which are almost always neutral) and **planar monsters (outsiders with alignments other than those listed are unusual and typically outcasts from their kind).** Note "type" and "subtypes" are not capitalized. Each type and subtype should be appropriately linked, as many of them provide special abilities.

(**emphasis** mine)

The description here makes clear that while aligned outsiders are fairly fixed in their native alignment, they *can* change. Fallen angels, repentant fiends, rogue robots, and so on.

Dungeons and Dragons certainly made occasional plot points of such anomalies, such as Falls-from-Grace from *Planescape: Torment* (LN succubus), and even a demonic *paladin*. As discussed in a [similar question for 3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30172/4563), the rules are a little more explicit about how this works, however.

Comment: So a PC could start with the alingmanet but could change (according to normal alignemnt rules) same for NPC  and also they are not necessarily having to start with that alingment?

Comment: @ThomasE. They could change, yes, or they could start with a different alignment (and thus said change happened before the game started). The only thing it *really* says is that they are born with the alignment, and it's difficult/rare for them to change.

Comment: I see tnx a lot there!

Answer (score 2):

**Must a half-fiend be evil?
No, it doesn't *have* to be.**

As a reference, in Savage Species* on p.102 it says this:

> When a kind of creature **always** has a particular alignment, individuals
> who differ are either **unique or one in a million**.
>
> When a creature **usually** has a particular alignment, individuals who
> differ are in the **minority** (considerably less than 50% of the
> population).
>
> When a creature **often** has a particular alignment, exceptions are
> **common**.

In your specific case, Half-Fiend is "always evil", which means that theres a one-in-a-million chance of him being the one Half-Fiend who has a non-evil alignment (but in that case it can be any alignment, even a good one, it does not have to be only one step away). **For a PC, that is still acceptable.**

However, I strongly suggest to rule alignment-stuff by logic (and the "fluff" behind it that explains how/why the character is a half-fiend and a nice guy at the same time) rather than rules.

*You can see [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/45699/15429) for a [fully Pathfinder-specific rules-reference](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-entry-format).